# Finding a limit of a rational function when the function isnt moving towards 0

Tags: limits, rational-functions

Consider this:

$$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{x^2+3x-4}{x^2-7x+10}$$ Now I've solved this for the case when x is approaching 0,but when I try to use the same method for when it is approaching 2,I dont get very far.So first I put in 2 and got that in the numerator we get a 2 and denominator we get a 0,so division by 0 we want to avoid that.Now I need to "change" the look of my polynomials to get the limit,but I'm not sure how to do that? I am not sure if I can use L'Hospital here since it isn't 0/0 but rather 2 divided by zero? A bit of advice would be much appreciated

Many thanks!

Comment: The numerator approaches $6$, and the denominator approaches $0$, so the limit does not exist. Factor out $x-2$ from the denominator and approach form left and right to see if it approaches $\infty$ or $-\infty$. P.S.: “polynomial”, not “polynom”.

Comment: I would consider the limit of the reciprocal and apply the sum/quotient rule, (and check if you have a sign change).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $x^2-7x+10=(x-2)(x-5)$. Therefore your limit is$$\lim_{x\to2}\frac{\frac{x^2+3x-4}{x-5}}{x-2}.\tag1$$Since $\lim_{x\to2}\frac{x^2+3x-4}{x-5}=-2$, the limit $(1)$ doesn't exist, because$$\lim_{x\to2^+}\frac{\frac{x^2+3x-4}{x-5}}{x-2}=-\infty\quad\text{and}\quad\lim_{x\to2^-}\frac{\frac{x^2+3x-4}{x-5}}{x-2}=\infty.$$

Comment: Huh okay well that helps a lot.. So actually it was all about factorizing the denominator.Although I have one question, since we know the limit of $$\frac{x^2+3x-4}{x-5} $$ is -2, and now if we put-2 in the (1) limes dont we get -2/0? How can we know that it is moving to infinity?

Comment: No, we don't get $-\frac20$, since the limit, if it exists, must be a real number or $\pm\infty$. But, when $x$ approaches $2$ by values greater than $2$, then the numerator approaches $-2$ and the denominator approaches $0$ by values greater than $0$; therefore, the quotient approaches $-\infty$. And  when $x$ approaches $2$ by values smaller than $2$, then the numerator approaches $-2$ and the denominator approaches $0$ by values smaller than $0$; therefore, the quotient approaches $\infty$.

Comment: Okay perfect,now I get it.Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

The rational function can be written as
$$
q(x)=\frac{x^2+3x-4}{x^2-7x+10}=\frac{(x+4)(x-1)}{(x-2)(x-5)}=\frac{1}{x-2}\cdot \frac{(x+4)(x-1)}{x-5}=:\frac{1}{x-2}\cdot g(x)
$$

Note that
$$
\lim_{x\to 2}g(x)=-2
$$
But $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 2}\frac{1}{x-2}$ does not exist.<sup>$\dagger$</sup> So the whole limit $\lim_{x\to 2}q(x)$, does not exist since otherwise, by one of the limit laws:
$$
\lim_{x\to 2}\frac{1}{x-2}=\frac{\lim_{x\to 2}q(x)}{\lim_{x\to 2}g(x)}
$$

---

<sup>$\dagger$</sup> Notes.

This is a case where you should go over the materials about two-sided limits.

The following two limits show that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}$ does not exist:
$$
\lim_{x\to 0-}\frac{1}{x},\quad \lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{1}{x}
$$

In general, $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists if and only if
$$
\lim_{x\to a-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to a+}f(x)=L
$$
where $L$ is a real number. $L$ could also be $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ if you want to deal with generalized limits.

Comment: what is the meaning of the notation "$\dagger$" in your answer?

Comment: @Soheil: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagger_(typography)

Comment: Interesting, do you also use this notation in handwriting notes?

Comment: well, it is for typography I suppose.